# Remove #{word} from a string using regex (python)

Tags: python, regex

I'm not familiar with regex, and it would be great to have some help.

I have a string:  `string = "You get #{turns} guesses."`
and I would like to remove `#{turns}` in order to have `string = "You get guesses."`

I've tried it with:

```
string = re.sub(re.compile('#{.*?}'),"",string)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about `string = string.replace("#{turns} ","")` ?

Comment: Well it works except that the spaces do not disappear...

Comment: What's not working with what you have?

Answer (score 2):

For this specific question you can also do it like so:

```
import re

string = "You get #{turns} guesses."
re.sub(r'#\S+ ', r'', string)
```

Output:

```
'You get guesses.'
```

Regex:

`'#\S+ '` Match # and match as many non space characters and a single space.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, except that it does not remove a sufficient amount of spaces and that compilation is rather useless if you only use it once:

```
>>> string = "You get #{turns} guesses."
>>> string = re.sub(re.compile('#{.*?}'),"",string)
>>> string
'You get  guesses.'
```

So you probably want to compile the regex once, and then use it, and you better alter it to - for instance - remove tailing spaces:

```
rgx = re.compile('#{.*?}\s*')
string = rgx.sub('',string)
```

Note the `\s*` which will match with an arbitrary amount of spaces **after** the tag, and thus remove these as well:

```
>>> string = "You get #{turns} guesses."
>>> rgx = re.compile('#{.*?}\s*')
>>> string = rgx.sub('',string)
>>> string
'You get guesses.'
```

In case it is **one word** between the curly brackets (`{}`), you better use `\w` to exclude spaces:

```
rgx = re.compile('#{\w*}\s*')
```